# Replace one div with another when navigation bar reaches certain position with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a fixed top navigation bar. The website is one page scroll type, with many pages to scroll over (like apple.com was in the past with smooth scroll).

What I am trying to do is that when my navigation bar is scrolled over a div with id #example, to change the div that contains the website navigation links from navigation bar, with other div with that contains a message.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work because the navigation bar is fixed, so it's always on top of the screen, it's not considered scrolling. It worked before implementing one-page-scroll function. Is there a way to detect if navigation bar IS OVER the div with id #example?

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scroll() == $("#example")) <!-- When it worked i had a number of pixels instead of the id of the div-->
    {   
        $(".navigation-links").hide("slow", function() {});
        $(".message-div").show("slow", function() {});
    }
    else
    {   
        $(".message-div").hide("slow", function() {});
        $(".navigation-links").show("slow", function() {});
    }
});
```

And this is my navigation bar:

```
<div class="fixed-nav-bar">
    <div class="navigation-links">
    </div>

    <div class="message-div" hidden>
        <p>Start Now</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/1059101

Comment: I think you can use [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) in your `if` statement..

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($( document ).scrollTop() >= $( "#example" ).offset().top && $( document ).scrollTop() < $( "#example" ).offset().top + 50) {
         $( ".navbar" ).text("second content");
    } else if($( document ).scrollTop() <= $( "#example" ).offset().top && $( document ).scrollTop() > $( "#example" ).offset().top - 50) {
        $( ".navbar" ).text("first content");
    }
});
```

### demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UbnQ4/7/

Comment: I tried now. It doesn't work. Maybe if I had a normal scroll it would have worked, but I have similar to this: [link](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)